# Is it possible that a child process can modify memory in the parent?

Tags: linux

This is twilight zone stuff.  We bumped into this on Ubuntu.  It looks like errno in a parent process was modified by its child process. We see this in code that is executed before main, in a constructor for a shared library.

Is this even possible?  Has anyone seen anything like this?

If errno is in a vdso, could it be that those pages aren't mapped to the child until main is ready to start?  That seems crazy.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible that a child process can modify memory in the parent?

Only if it comes from a `vfork()` or a `clone()` call with CLONE_VM (*not* from a `fork()` call), or if that memory is shared memory (`mmap()`ed MAP_SHARED memory counts as shared memory).